# Ceph RBD in CoreOS

Tags: docker, coreos, ceph

I am working on a platform which my company can use to host containerized application for out own purposes.

We use the following solution: PXE server -> PXE boot CoreOS -> Docker -> Ceph cluster in Docker containers.

Everything works great, we have built our own provisioning-service which uses Ignition-files to configure the host. The last step (Mounting Ceph Block Device) is the biggest issue for me.

When I mount it in CentOS7 it's pretty simple, I only need to install ceph-common and everything works like charm, but now I need to be able to mount it inside a Docker container on CoreOS.

What is really the best practice to achieve this? I would really appreciate an example or link to article about it as every guide I come across is simply 3 or 4 years old and the solutions don't work anymore.

Comment: Are you using an orchestration service on top of your nodes? If so there are several options to deploy a Ceph cluster that are highly automated

Answer (score -1):

CoreOS is specifically designed not to have packages installed on it directly, but instead to have systems composed on top of it using containers.

To use Ceph on CoreOS then, you need to use containers to run the Ceph applications on the hosts and mount the required devices and host paths into the container. There is a basic overview (though somewhat out-of-date, being from 2015) in the [Ceph blog](https://ceph.com/geen-categorie/bootstrap-your-ceph-cluster-in-docker/).